# Based on the value in one column change the value in another column

Tags: r

I created a table "examres" like this

```
         names marks result
1       dinesh    60   pass
2       aiysha    70   pass
3         ravi    40   fail
4       rajesh    55   pass
5     achyuthy    80   pass
6      snigdha    30   fail
7      mounica     0   pass
8                 55   pass
9                  0   fail
10      mourya     0   pass
11 deepa sinde    25       
12 hima sekhar    55   pass
13                30   fail
14      dhatri    60
```

In the above table I want to change the result column based on the "marks" column and my condition is marks<50 "fail" else "pass"

I used:

```
ifelse(examres$marks<50,examres$result<-"fail",examres$result<-"pass")
```

but its not working.

Comment: in the same way can you suggest me how to make the empty values in the "examres$names" column to replace with "NULL" ,It would help me a lot please

Comment: @Dinesh empty values in which column?

Comment: It is better to replace the empty strings `''` with `NA` as `NULL` cannot be used in a vector or data.frame columns unless it is a character string (which makes it no better than `''`)

Comment: @akrun how to  replace the empty strings '' with NA plese

Comment: @Dinesh there are many ways, `is.na(examres$names) <- examres$names==''` (assuming that the names column is character class

Answer (score 3):

It was almost correct, try this:

```
examres$result <- ifelse(examres$marks<50,"fail","pass")
```

> ifelse - Description
>
> ifelse returns a value with the same shape as test which is filled
>   with elements selected from either yes or no depending on whether the
>   element of test is TRUE or FALSE.
>
> Usage
>   ifelse(test, yes, no)

To change names to NA when it is blank - `""`:

```
examres$names[examres$names == ""] <- NA
```

Note, use `na.strings` options when [reading in the file](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html). Then we would avoid NA problem altogether.

Comment: Other options include `as.character(factor(examres$marks < 50, labels=c('pass', 'fail')))` or `c('pass', 'fail')[(examres$marks < 50)+1L]`

Comment: @Pascal as it stands it is hard to tell what qualifies as *empty*. But the logic is basically simple and the same, find empty and replace with `NA`.

Comment: If there are spaces then `examres$names[grep('^\\s*$', examres$names)] <- NA`