# Setting values to NA in one column based on conditions in another column

Tags: r

Here's a simplified mock dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(amb = c(2.5,3.6,2.1,2.8,3.4,3.2,1.3,2.5,3.2),
                  warm = c(3.6,5.3,2.1,6.3,2.5,2.1,2.4,6.2,1.5),
                  sensor = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3))
```

I'd like to set all values in the "amb" column to NA if they're in sensor 1, but retain the values in the "warm" column for sensor 1. Here's what I'd like the final output to look like:

```
amb  warm  sensor
NA   3.6   1
NA   5.3   1
NA   2.1   1
2.8  6.3   2
3.4  2.5   2
3.2  2.1   2
1.3  2.4   3
2.5  6.2   3
3.2  1.5   3
```

Using R version 4.0.2, Mac OS X 10.13.6

Comment: try `df1$amb[df1$sensor == 1] <- NA`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Based on the value in one column change the value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774096/based-on-the-value-in-one-column-change-the-value-in-another-column)

Answer (score 2):

A  possible solution, based on `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(amb = ifelse(sensor == 1, NA, amb))

#>   amb warm sensor
#> 1  NA  3.6      1
#> 2  NA  5.3      1
#> 3  NA  2.1      1
#> 4 2.8  6.3      2
#> 5 3.4  2.5      2
#> 6 3.2  2.1      2
#> 7 1.3  2.4      3
#> 8 2.5  6.2      3
#> 9 3.2  1.5      3
```

Comment: Maybe this one is better? `df1 %>% 
  mutate(amb = if_else(sensor == 1, NA_real_, amb))`

Comment: Maybe, @TarJae! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be best handled with the vectorized function `is.na<-`

```
is.na(df1$amb) <- df1$sensor %in% c(1)  # that c() isn't needed
```

But to be most general and support tests of proper test for equality among floating point numbers the answer might be:

```
is.na(df1$amb) <- df1$sensor-1 < 1e-16
```